# string matching with NLP

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp, string-matching

I have two `dataframes`, `df1` and `df2`, with ~40,000 rows and ~70,000 rows respectively of data about polling stations in country A.

The two dataframes have some common columns like 'polling_station_name', 'province', 'district' etc., however `df1` has latitude and longitude columns, whereas `df2` doesn't, so I am trying to do `string matching` between the two dataframes so at least some rows of `df2` will have geolocations available. I am blocking on the 'district' column while doing the string matching.

This is the code that I have so far:

```
import recordlinkage
from recordlinkage.standardise import clean
indexer = recordlinkage.Index()
indexer.block('district')
candidate_links = indexer.index(df1, df2) 

compare = recordlinkage.Compare()
compare.string('polling_station_name', 'polling_station_name', method='damerau_levenshtein', threshold=0.75)
compare_vectors = compare.compute(candidate_links, df1, df2)
```

This produced about 12,000 matches, however I have noticed that some polling station names are incorrectly being matched because their names are very similar when they are in different locations - e.g. `'government girls primary school meilabu'` and `'government girls primary school muzaka'` are clearly different, yet they are being matched.

I think utilising NLP might help here, to see if there are certain words that occur very frequently in the data, like `'government'`, `'girls'`, `'boys'`, `'primary'`, `'school'`, etc. so I can put less emphasis on those words, and put more emphasis on `meilabu`, `muzaka` etc. while doing the string matching, but I am not so sure where to start.
(For reference, many of the polling stations are 'government (i.e.public) schools')

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The topic is very broad, just pay attention to standard approaches:

- **TFIDF**: term frequency–inverse document frequency is often used as a weighting factor.
- Measure similarity between two sentences using **cosine similarity**

Answer (score 0):

@ipj said it correct, the topic is very broad. You can try out below methods,

```
def get_sim_measure(sentence1, sentence1):
    vec1 = get_vector(sentence1)
    vec2 = get_vector(sentence2)
    return cosine_similarity(vec1, vec2)
```

Now the `get_vector` method can be many things.

- Remove the stop words first and then you can use word2vec, GloVe on a word level and average them for the sentence. (simple)
- Use doc2vec from Gensim for vector embedding of the sentence. (medium)
- Use Bert (DistilBert or something lighter) for dynamic embedding with context. (hard)
- Use TF-IDF and then use GloVe embedding. (simple)
- Use spaCy's entity recognition and then do similarity matching (in this case words from `government girls primary school` will act as stop words) on entity labels. (slow process but simple)
- Use BleuScore for measuring the similar words (in case you need it). (maybe misguiding)

There can be many situations, so better give few simple ones a try and go ahead.